# Display a webpage within a webpage and bypass cross-origin framing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to bypass a block preventing cross-origin framing and display webpages in an HTML document ?
With any technology— js, JQuery, server-side ?

Comment: Now why would you want to do that? Clearly if their site blocks you it's for good reason right? Try your luck with file_get_contents('http....') PHP - doubt it will work, but neither will any client side code.

Comment: if cross-origin framing is blocked I don't see how it could be possible client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If their server blocks cross-origin framing, it's blocked and there's no good way around it.

But... going back to simple HTML, you could always use an `iframe`.

Comment: iframes can be blocked by cross-origin framing too!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to do something like this but you could take a look at [PHP Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)